# Puppeteer: error al obtener url

Tags: nodejs, typescript, puppeteer, web-scrapping, bot

Estoy intentando simular un login a través de [puppeteer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer) para poder automatizar una serie de tests os dejo [aquí](https://pptr.dev/) el link a la documentación.

En este login que debo realizar hay 3 pasos:

1.- Rellenar formulario con credenciales, pulsar "Login" -> FUNCIONA OK 
2.- Redirección a otra web al hacer login donde se debe pulsar "Continuar" para iniciar sesión -> FUNCIONA OK 
3.- Redirección a una última web SIN CONTENIDO, donde en la URL aparece un parámeto con el valor que necesito, de esta forma: "https://XXXXXXX.com?PARAMETRO=MI_VALOR_DESEADO" -> NO OK

Os comparto el código, por motivos de seguridad las URLs no son las reales:

```
import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";

const bot = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

/*PASO 1 - LOGIN*/
    await page.goto('https://access_page_login.com')

    const user = await page.$('#documento');
    await user?.type('USERNAME');
    
    const password = await page.$('#inputpassword');
    await password?.type('USERPASSWORD');

    let url = await page.url();
    await console.log(url); // --> FUNCIONA OK, IMPRIME BIEN URL

    await page.screenshot({path: '1-credentialsForm.png'}); //  --> FUNCIONA OK, APARECE IMAGEN CON FORM RELLENO

    let btn = await page.$('#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > button');

    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        btn?.click()
    ]);

/*PASO 2 - CONTINUAR */
    btn = await page.$('body > div > div > div > main > div > div > div._bottom30._display-flex._top30 > button');

    url = await page.url();
    await console.log(url); // --> FUNCIONA OK, IMPRIME BIEN URL

    await page.screenshot({path: '2-continue.png'}); // --> FUNCIONA OK, APARECE IMAGEN CON BTN CONTINUAR

    await Promise.all([
        page.waitForNavigation(),
        btn?.click()
    ]);

/* PASO 3 - OBTENCIÓN PARÁMETRO */
    url = await page.url();
    await console.log(url); // ERROR -> IMPRIME: chrome-error://chromewebdata/

    await page.screenshot({path: '3-end.png'}); // ERROR -> APARECE IMAGEN EN BLANCO


    console.log(await browser.pages()); 
    await browser.close();


};


bot();
```

Veo 3 comportamientos que no son los deseados: 
1.- No obtengo URL en el paso 3 -> En vez de la URL recibo: chrome-error://chromewebdata/ 
2.- Screenshot del paso 3 -> Debería obtener un screenshot como este:
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
Pero obtengo un screenshot en blanco. 
3.- Ejecución de `console.log(await browser.pages());` obtengo un array de objetos como este:

```
[
  Page {
    eventsMap: Map(0) {},
    emitter: {
      all: Map(0) {},
      on: [Function: on],
      off: [Function: off],
      emit: [Function: emit]
    }
  },
  Page {
    eventsMap: Map(0) {},
    emitter: {
      all: Map(0) {},
      on: [Function: on],
      off: [Function: off],
      emit: [Function: emit]
    }
  }
]
```

Es decir, solo está realizando un redireccionamiento. Debería haber 3 Pages.

Destacar que todos los selectores para los botones, los obtengo abriendo las herramientas de desarrollador y copiando el selector directamente.
Además, todo este proceso de login se lo realizo de forma manual, funciona correctamente y sin problemas desde Edge, Chrome, Firefox...

Si has llegado hasta aquí, gracias por molestarte.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida, un saludo.

**EDIT 1**
Si añado la siguiente configuración al launcher:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        slowMo: 100,
        defaultViewport: {
            width: 1200,
            height: 768
        }
 });
```

Puedo ir viendo lo que el bot realiza en tiempo real con un navegador que se abre automáticamente. Y aquí SI aparece la URL que necesito, con el parámetro que necesito, pero al intentar obtener la URL, aparece el chrome-error://chromewebdata/

¿A qué se debe este comportamiento? ¿Por qué no puedo recoger la URL con el comando `page.url()` pero en el navegador que abre el bot en tiempo real SI puedo ver dicha URL?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JW4p.png

Comment: en el launch de puppeteer probá con `args: [  "--disable-web-security", ]` si hay un oauth con redirecciones entre dominios/subdominios puede ser que falle con un `chrome-error://chromewebdata/` [ref args](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#disable-web-security)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola buenas conseguí dar con la solución.

Os comparto a la solución que llegué por si os es de ayuda:

No fui capaz de conseguir captar la url a la que era redireccionado a través de `await page.url()`. Para mi caso concreto esta URL también podía obtenerla a través de los headers de una respuesta HTTP, por lo tanto añadí el siguiente bloque de código:

```
page.on('response', async response => {
    console.log(await response.headers());
  });
```

Esto tampoco me funcionó, al haber demasiadas peticiones http puppeteer tardaba demasiado en realizar todas las peticiones y recoger sus respuestas, tanto que siempre obtenía un error de timeout. Por lo tanto después de muchos intentos realicé lo siguiente:

```
 try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            headless: false,
            args: ['--headless']
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
    
        await page.goto('https://access_page_login.com');
    
        const user = await page.$('#documento');
        await user?.type('USERNAME');
        
        const password = await page.$('#inputpassword');
        await password?.type('USERPASSWORD');
    
        let btn = await page.$('#loginForm > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > button');
    
        await Promise.all([
            page.waitForNavigation(),
            btn?.click()
        ]);
    
        /*****/
        btn = await page.$('body > div > div > div > main > div > div > div._bottom30._display-flex._top30 > button');
    
        await btn?.click();
        const finalResponse = await page.waitForResponse(async (response) => { 
            return response.status() === 303;
        });
    
        const location = finalResponse.headers().location;// Aquí está la url que necesito

        browser.close();    
        
        return location;    
    } catch(e) {
        return e;
    }
```

Como podéis ver eliminé el código:

```
await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation(),
      btn?.click()
]);
```

y lo sustituí por:

```
await btn?.click();
const finalResponse = await page.waitForResponse(async (response) => { 
      return response.status() === 303;
});
```

Anteriormente parece que puppeteer me redireccionaba demasiado rápido por lo que no llegaba a recoger la URL que necesitaba. A través de la función `waitForResponse()` obligamos a puppeteer a esperar el tiempo que sea necesario hasta que reciba todas las respuestas a las peticiones HTTP de esta página (incluyendo las que se realizan al hacer click en el botón que redirecciona a la tercera página). Por lo tanto una vez esperamos a todas las peticiones que finalicen, filtramos la que necesitamos por código de estado, en mi caso 303, y BINGO! Obtuve la respuesta, con el header de redireccionamiento, con la URL que necesito.

Fui incapaz de llegar al resultado a través de `await page.url()` que entiendo que sería la forma más óptima y limpia. Estuve leyendo en muchos foros y parece que las páginas SPA a veces no se comportan como deberían a la hora de obtener redireccionamientos.

Espero que os sea de ayuda.